# How to group by api repsons weekly datewise in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I am getting below response from api .
Below is sample respone  not real
Each object has createdDate , I have to group value is weekwise wise like.
like  2022-10-01 and 2022-10-02 both are 1st week of Oct , and 2022-10-10 3rd Week of Oct

```
{
  "data": {
    "fetchOrdersAndRequest": [
      {
        "id": "PI786971",
        "customerId": [
          "C200147"
        ],
        "createdDate": "2022-10-01T04:46:00.126Z",
        }
         {
        "id": "PI786972",
        "customerId": [
          "C200148"
        ],
        "createdDate": "2022-10-02T04:46:00.126Z",
        }
         {
        "id": "PI786972",
        "customerId": [
          "C200149"
        ],
        "createdDate": "2022-10-10T04:46:00.126Z",
        }
        {
        "id": "PI786969",
        "customerId": [
          "C200146"
        ],
        "createdDate": "2022-10-24T04:46:00.126Z",
        }
        
        {
        "id": "PI786968",
        "customerId": [
          "C200145"
        ],
        "createdDate": "2022-10-29T04:46:00.126Z",
        }
        
        ]
        }
        }
```

I have to convert the response like below , monthly value I have to convert weekly

```
 {
    period:'lastMonth',
    Week:[
        {
            "key":"Week1",
            "value" : [{
            "id": "PI786971",
            "customerId": [
            "C200147"
        ],
        "createdDate": "2022-10-01T04:46:00.126Z",
        }
         {
        "id": "PI786972",
        "customerId": [
          "C200148"
        ],
        "createdDate": "2022-10-02T04:46:00.126Z",
        }],
            "date": [{2022-10-01}{2022-10-02}]
        },
        {
            "key":"Week2",
            "value" : [],
            "date:[]
        },
        {
            "key":"Week3",
            "value" : [{
            "id": "PI786972",
            "customerId": [
            "C200149"
        ],
        "createdDate": "2022-10-10T04:46:00.126Z",
        }],
            "date":[{2022-10-10}]
        },
        {
            "key":"Week4",
            "value" : [{}],
        },
        {
            "key":"week5",
            "value" : []
            "date":[{2022-10-24}{2022-10-29}]
        },
        {
            "key":"Week6",
            "value" : [],
            "date:[]
        },
        
    ]
```

// Using below code I am able to filter weeks  and my weeks startng from sunday to Saturday  , but now I have to puch my api response data matching to dates

```
fetchMonthWeek = ()=>{
      var today = new Date();
      const month = today.getMonth() + 1
      const year = today.getFullYear()
      var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
      let weeks = {}
    
      var totalDays = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
      let weekCount = 1
      for (let i = 1; i <= totalDays; i++) {
        const date = (i < 10 ? '0' + i : i)
        const fullDate = (year + '-' + (month < 10 ? '0' + month : month) + '-' + date)
        const currentDay = days[new Date(fullDate).getDay()]
        if (currentDay === days[0]) weekCount++
        const w = 'Week' + weekCount
        if (weeks[w]) {
          weeks[w].push(fullDate)
        } else weeks[w] = [fullDate]
      }
      console.log(weeks)
      let newData = []
      for (const w in weeks) {
        newData.push({
          key: w,
          range: {
            startDate: weeks[w][0],
            endDate: weeks[w][weeks[w].length - 1]
          },
          value: weeks[w]
        })
      }

      return newData
     }
```

Please help .
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure about 6 weeks?

Comment: @ Sonu  Thanks for your response , yes I have to mak elike that like in oct 1st week 1 and 2 oct  and in last week 31 so like that way  I am making .. if possible else 4 week

Comment: @SonuBamniya  Is it possible ? its kind off customize . Please sugegst

Comment: Yes, I think you will need moment or any other similar library to do that.

Comment: @SonuBamniya could you please help , I am getting succes in it